# Plot.ly refuses to change orientation of the legend of my chart

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, plotly

I simply want to change orientation of the legend block to horizontal, but it always displays in vertical. Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
  newData.traces = newData.traces
  .filter(trace => trace.name === 'Self Pay' || trace.name === 'Bank Loan')
  .map(trace => {
    return {
      ...trace,
      mode: 'lines+markers',
      fillcolor: colors[trace.name].fill,
      fill: 'tozeroy',
      line: {
        color: colors[trace.name].line
      }
    };
  });
  newData.layout = {
    ...newData.layout,
    yaxis: {
      ...newData.layout.yaxis,
      title: 'TOTAL SAVINGS (1K)'
    },
    xaxis: {
      ...newData.layout.xaxis,
      title: 'YEARS SINCE INSTALLATION'
    },
    legend: {
      orientation: 'h',
      y: 1.30,
      x: 0.25
    },
    paper_bgcolor: 'transparent',
    plot_bgcolor: 'transparent'
  };
  console.log("newData.layout: ", newData.layout);
  newData.traces = newData.traces.filter(t => data.modeStatus[t.name]);
  Plotly.newPlot($(chart).attr('id'), newData.traces, newData.layout, {displayModeBar: false});
```

As you can see, the way I generate the layout object is a bit convoluted, but `legend` object clearly has `orientation: 'h'`, so it's supposed to show the legend horizontally, right?

Here's a screenshot of the relevant chart and the output in the console:

[image: screenshot of chart]

Any idea what could possible cause such a problem? I'm pretty sure that at one point it was working correctly, but then for some unknown reason it kept rendering the legend block vertically.

Here's a picture of the desired result:

[image: the desired result]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by horizontal orientation? alignment of the legend on the horizontal axis or alignment of the legend elements next to each other? The first case is actually achieved by your code.

Comment: I meant next to each other, sorry if it's not clear. I will my update my post with a picture of the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Is it possible that the issue is caused by some other layout issue, CSS, whatever? The orientation works fine in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/10y29wy0/